# @formatjs/intl-localematcher pathname translate

Tags: reactjs, next.js13, formatjs

I use this package to change the @formatjs/intl-localematcher language in my nextjs 14 app router project and I want the parts of the url to change when the language changes: For example: /hakkinda TR language => /about in En language